# load data in exact order from json string(python, django)

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I have json data coming from ajax,jquery as below

```
json_data_from_ajax = u'{"1_sd":{"name":"unicode","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"2_sd":{"name":"unicode_secret","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"3_sd":{"name":"unicode_mandatory","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"4_sd":{"name":"boolean","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"5_sd":{"name":"boolean_secret","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"6_sd":{"name":"boolean_mandatory","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"7_sd":{"name":"integer","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"8_sd":{"name":"integer_value","data_type_choices":"Unicode"},"9_sd":{"name":"integer_mandatory","data_type_choices":"Unicode"}}'
```

And i am trying to load(convert json string in to actual data) the above data as below

import json as simplejson
settings_records = simplejson.loads(json_data_from_ajax)
print settings_records

***output***

```
{u'8_sd': {u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'3_sd': {u'name': u'unicode_mandatory', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'1_sd': {u'name': u'unicode', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'6_sd': {u'name': u'boolean_mandatory', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'9_sd': {u'name': u'integer_mandatory', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'4_sd': {u'name': u'boolean', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'7_sd': {u'name': u'integer', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'2_sd': {u'name': u'unicode_secret', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}, u'5_sd': {u'name': u'boolean_secret', u'data_type_choices': u'Unicode'}}
```

So from the above output you can able to see that the keys from dictionary are ordered randomly like `u'8_sd', u'3_sd', u'1_sd'......`, but i need to them as it is from json string which i received from ajax like `"1_sd", "2_sd", "3_sd", "4_sd"......`

So how can we load the json string in an order ?

Comment: You cannot order the properties of an object. If you need to iterate through a set in a specific order you need to change the JSON to return an array of objects

Comment: Similarly, a Python dict is unordered. However, when dumping a Python data structure to JSON you can specify `sort_keys=True` to get the keys in each dict to be emitted in lexicographical order.

Answer (score 0):

This might help (doesn't work for python <2.7):

```
import simplejson as json
from collections import OrderedDict

settings_records = json.loads(json_data_from_ajax, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```